# How to bind a command to Entry "Unfocused" event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a command (or a piece of code) which I want to run when a specific entry loses its focus.

I'm using MVVM so I want to do it using the binding way instead of writing code in my `Form.xaml.cs`.

How can I make my command (or my piece of code) run when my entry loses its focus within `XAML` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an example of an `EventToCommandBehavior` in the Xamarin.Forms samples ([see here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs)). Using this you could bind your control

```xml
<Entry>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="Unfocused" 
            Command="{Binding EntryUnfocused}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Then define `EntryUnfocused` in your class of `viewmodel.cs` file of your particular view, like below:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel : XamarinViewModel
{
    public ICommand EntryUnfocused{ get; protected set; } 
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        EntryUnfocused= new Command(CompletedCommandExecutedAsync);
    }

    private void CompletedCommandExecutedAsync(object param)
    {
     //yourcode...
    }
}
```

If you are using the Prism library, you can use their implementation, which is a bit more mature (allowing you to map the event arguments by specifying, which parameter shall be passed), [see here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/EventToCommandBehavior.html).

(**Please note** that you'll have to add the respective namespace the behavior lives in to your XAML file).

Comment: Make sure to have the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit NuGet installed

Answer (score 3):

If you use Xamarin Community Toolkit, you can use `EventToCommandBehavior` which is already there.

Using this will be the same as in the Paul Kertscher answer.

Add to your control header:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

In your `Entry` bind to the command:

```
<Entry.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
        EventName="Unfocused"
        Command="{Binding EntryUnfocused}" />
</Entry.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Should this not be toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior ?